# Does django-reversion require me to re-define all of my model pre_save & post_save signals?

Tags: django, django-models, django-reversion

I recently added [django-reversion](https://github.com/etianen/django-reversion) to my project to keep a history of model changes. Now, any time I save a model in my system, I get the following warning in the log:

> .../site-packages/reversion/models.py:218: UserWarning: pre_save 
>   and post_save signals will not longer be sent for Revision and Version
>   models in django-reversion 1.8. Please use the pre_revision_commit and
>   post_revision_commit signals instead.

However, I'm not using the pre_save and post_save signals on the Revision and Version models *themselves*, or anything that extends those… Is this warning saying that I need to change the pre_save and post_save signals on any model in my project that makes use of versioning??

Answer (score 0):

No, the deprecated signals are not for **any model**, they are just for the Revision and Version models.  You can continue to use the pre_save and post_save signals on your own models.

http://django-reversion.readthedocs.org/en/latest/signals.html?highlight=post_save

I'm sure you've figured it out in the intervening 10 months, but I thought I'd clarify for the next visitor.